# how to get value from input data fragment with viewpager

Tags: android, android-activity, mobile, android-viewpager, fragment

i have 4 fragment in 1 activity (MainActivity: ViewPager)

fragment1 = edittext1, fragment2 = edittext2, fragment3 = edittext3 & fragment4 = buttonsave

in fragment4 there is only a save button to retrieve data from fragments 1,2 and 3
but when I click buttonsave, data from fragment1 is always null

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "FRAG1");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), "FRAG2");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), "FRAG3");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentFour(), "FRAG4");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**Fragment 1,2 dan 3**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
public FragmentOne() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}
```

}

**Fragment4**

```
public class FragmentFour extends Fragment {

private EditText txt1, txt2, txt3;
private Button button;

public FragmentFour() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_four, container, false);

    txt1 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt2 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    txt3 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt3);

    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getData();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void getData() {
    String fragment1 = txt1.getText().toString();
    String fragment2 = txt2.getText().toString();
    String fragment3 = txt3.getText().toString();
}
```

**Null Problem**

Data from text1 (fragment)always null:

[image: Data from text1 (fragment)always null]

what should i do to solve this problem?

many thanks...

Comment: you can use static variable

Comment: What about data from fragment 2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

viewPager always load 1 consecutive pages of both side if you want to access Fragment 1 editText data then add this line

```
 viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

or
         Use static variable

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Share preference** to store FragmentOne Data ,FragmentTwo Data and then retrieve in to FragmentTree on save button

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Arguments** to pass data between fragments, for example

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("someEditTextData",someEditTextData);
SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment ();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and retrieve the data in required fragment something like this

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        showReceivedData.setText(args.getString("someEditTextData"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared preference for this purpose

**Create SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DATA", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("EDITEXT1", "string value");  // Saving string data of your editext
editor.commit(); // commit and save your data in to SharedPreferences
```

now retrieve your data like below code

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DATA", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String email=pref.getString("EDITEXT1", "");       // Saving string data of your editext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a instance field in your activity and can access it by up casting getActivity() reference to MainActivity in fragment.

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).filedName.setFragmentOneData(data);
```